# Error 12006 in WinHttpCrackUrl

Tags: c++, dll, winhttp

I'm trying to build an address from a variable. So I can pass it to `WinHttpOpenRequest`.

```
    char *uNameAddr = (char*) ExeBaseAddress + 0x34F01C;
    printf("%s \n", uNameAddr);

    string url = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx/?u=";
    string username = uNameAddr;


    string combine = url + username;

    cout << combine << endl;
    //http://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx/?u=MyUsername <--

    URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;
    LPCWSTR pwszUrl1 = (LPCWSTR)combine.c_str();
    DWORD dwUrlLen = 0;
```

Then I have to pass it here:

```
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", urlComp.lpszUrlPath,
                               NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                               WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                               0);
```

`urlComp.lpszUrlPath` should be `http://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxxx/?u=MyUsername`

Any advice? My application crashes when it gets to process that part.

---

ERROR

```
 12006       ERROR_INTERNET_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME
             The URL scheme could not be recognized or is not supported.
```

Comment: `LPCWSTR pwszUrl1 = (LPCWSTR)combine.c_str();` Did you just put that cast in there to shut the compiler up? Stupid compiler, what would it know.

Comment: I guess. I'm new at this.

Comment: The subject says `WinHttpCrackUrl`, the provided code does not have it.

Answer (score 2):

```
LPCWSTR pwszUrl1 = (LPCWSTR)combine.c_str();
```

`std::string::c_str` returns `const char *`. [`LPCWSTR` is `const wchar_t *`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx).

Casting to `LPCWSTR` is lying to the compiler and yourself, what `combine.c_str()` returns is **not** a pointer to a wide-character string.

You'll likely have better success with `std::wstring`, which represents wide-character strings.

Consider reading [Unicode in the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.